# How to disable `zN<CR>` mappings in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

`zN<CR>` is described as follows:

```
z{height}<CR>      redraw, make window {height} lines high
```

This has been bugging me for a long time, as I usually use `z=` to jump to the previous wrongly spelled word, and then press <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select the top suggestion. (That is, a `z=1<CR>` sequence.)

This process is not robust, as I may miss the `=`. Then, the `z=1<CR>` sequence falls to `z1<CR>`, which gives me a one-line window. This turns to be very distracting.

**Is there a way to disable `z1<CR>` specifically? (`unmap z1<CR>` does not work, upon simple testing.) Or, to disable `zN<CR>` completely?**

So far, I am not using `zN`-functions at all, and would like to avoid the mishaps it triggers.

Currently, I am compromising to map the "correct previous wrongly spelled word by its first suggested correction" to `KK` in normal mode. (`nnoremap KK z=1<CR><ESC>`, with `<ESC>` in the end to jump out of a message box.)

Thank you!

All the best,

-Linfeng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first solution is, don't forget the `=` :-)
- If you mostly only use `z=1<cr>` to jump, you can just disable `z1<cr>` by:

  ```
  map z1<cr> <nop>
  ```

However if you pressed `z2<cr>` it will redraw the window anyway...

Hope it helps you a little.